# Responsive Datatable - shows datatable warning

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, datatables

I am using serverside datatable in my project. I would like to make the table responsive. I tried using the following code along with my code. Its working but I am getting a datatable warning.

**$('#myTable').DataTable( {
responsive: true
} );**

[image]

Comment: Share the code as well

Comment: Please share your code, this is not a responsive issue, it means the table doesn't understand the parameter you are posting for the second column in your DataTable. See there error here: [4. Warning: Requested unknown parameter](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4). Please add your table initialization as well as your data structure

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the table with div and table-responsive class. Example : `<div class="table-responsive"><table></table></div>`